# Parse a JSON Output in Ansible to display information in nested display

Tags: ansible, f5

I am trying to run a playbook that queries our F5 for a specific pool and displays only what I need. I can parse any data directly under ltm_pools but if it is a subset like "members" i can't filter specific info for that. I want to filter specific info for the members subset. You can see I have members listed as an output display but it displays every field under members. I want to filter for specific fields like "name" under the "members" field.

See the JSON OUtput:

```json
  "ltm_pools": [
        {
            "all_max_queue_entry_age_recently": 0,
            "pool_queue_head_entry_age": 0,
            "current_sessions": 0,
            "pool_max_queue_entry_age_recently": 0,
            "server_side_max_connections": 0,
            "monitors": [
                "/Common/tcp"
            ],
            "available_member_count": 0,
            "server_side_bits_in": 0,
            "pool_max_queue_entry_age_ever": 0,
            "member_count": 4,
            "priority_group_activation": 0,
            "allow_snat": "yes",
            "reselect_tries": 0,
            "enabled_status": "enabled",
            "active_member_count": 0,
            "server_ip_tos": "pass-through",
            "server_link_qos": "pass-through",
            "queue_on_connection_limit": "no",
            "queue_depth_limit": 0,
            "minimum_up_members_action": "failover",
            "allow_nat": "yes",
            "lb_method": "round-robin",
            "all_avg_queue_entry_age": 0,
            "ignore_persisted_weight": "no",
            "server_side_bits_out": 0,
            "all_num_connections_serviced": 0,
            "minimum_active_members": 0,
            "service_down_action": "none",
            "server_side_current_connections": 0,
            "members": [
                {
                    "real_session": "monitor-enabled",
                    "rate_limit": "no",
                    "inherit_profile": "yes",
                    "real_state": "down",
                    "address": "1.1.1.1",
                    "logging": "no",
                    "monitors": [],
                    "ratio": 1,
                    "name": "1.1.1.1:3268",
                    "partition": "Common",
                    "ephemeral": "no",
                    "connection_limit": 0,
                    "state": "offline",
                    "full_path": "/Common/1.1.1.1:3268",
                    "fqdn_autopopulate": "no",
                    "priority_group": 0,
                    "dynamic_ratio": 1
                },
                {
                    "real_session": "monitor-enabled",
                    "rate_limit": "no",
                    "inherit_profile": "yes",
                    "real_state": "down",
                    "address": "2.2.2.2",
                    "logging": "no",
                    "monitors": [],
                    "ratio": 1,
                    "name": "2.2.2.2:3268",
                    "partition": "Common",
                    "ephemeral": "no",
                    "connection_limit": 0,
                    "state": "offline",
                    "full_path": "/Common/2.2.2.2:3268",
                    "fqdn_autopopulate": "no",
                    "priority_group": 0,
                    "dynamic_ratio": 1
                },
                {
                    "real_session": "monitor-enabled",
                    "rate_limit": "no",
                    "inherit_profile": "yes",
                    "real_state": "down",
                    "address": "3.3.3.3",
                    "logging": "no",
                    "monitors": [],
                    "ratio": 1,
                    "name": "3.3.3.3:3268",
                    "partition": "Common",
                    "ephemeral": "no",
                    "connection_limit": 0,
                    "state": "offline",
                    "full_path": "/Common/3.3.3.3:3268",
                    "fqdn_autopopulate": "no",
                    "priority_group": 0,
                    "dynamic_ratio": 1
                },
                {
                    "real_session": "monitor-enabled",
                    "rate_limit": "no",
                    "inherit_profile": "yes",
                    "real_state": "down",
                    "address": "3.3.3.3",
                    "logging": "no",
                    "monitors": [],
                    "ratio": 1,
                    "name": "3.3.3.3:3268",
                    "partition": "Common",
                    "ephemeral": "no",
                    "connection_limit": 0,
                    "state": "offline",
                    "full_path": "/Common/3.3.3.3:3268",
                    "fqdn_autopopulate": "no",
                    "priority_group": 0,
                    "dynamic_ratio": 1
                }
            ],
            "all_max_queue_entry_age_ever": 0,
            "queue_time_limit": 0,
            "status_reason": "The children pool member(s) are down",
            "server_side_pkts_out": 0,
            "server_side_total_connections": 0,
            "pool_num_connections_serviced": 0,
            "client_link_qos": "pass-through",
            "name": "test",
            "pool_num_connections_queued_now": 0,
            "minimum_up_members": 0,
            "all_queue_head_entry_age": 0,
            "slow_ramp_time": 10,
            "server_side_pkts_in": 0,
            "client_ip_tos": "pass-through",
            "minimum_up_members_checking": "no",
            "all_num_connections_queued_now": 0,
            "availability_status": "offline",
            "pool_avg_queue_entry_age": 0,
            "total_requests": 0,
            "full_path": "/Common/test"
        },
```

This is my playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: collect device info
    bigip_device_info:
      gather_subset:
        - ltm-pools
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: f5pools

# Show the name, IP address, port and status of a virtual server
  - name: Display Config for a specific Virtual Server using a variable
    debug:
     var: item
    loop: "{{ f5pools | json_query(pool_name) }}"
    vars:
     pool_name: "ltm_pools[?name=='{{ poolName }}'].{name: name, Method: lb_method, Members: members Monitors: monitors}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest a JMESPath query inside a multiselect, in your case, to achieve what you are looking for.

So instead of using plain

```yaml
Members: members
```

In your multiselect, you can use something like

```yaml
Members: members[*].{name: name}
```

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - name: Display Config for a specific Virtual Server using a variable
      debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ f5pools | json_query(pool_name) }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.name }}"
      vars:
        pool_name: "ltm_pools[?name=='{{ poolName }}'].{name: name, Method: lb_method, Members: members[*].{name: name}, Monitors: monitors}"
        f5pools:
          ltm_pools:
            - all_max_queue_entry_age_recently: 0
              pool_queue_head_entry_age: 0
              current_sessions: 0
              pool_max_queue_entry_age_recently: 0
              server_side_max_connections: 0
              monitors:
                - /Common/tcp
              available_member_count: 0
              server_side_bits_in: 0
              pool_max_queue_entry_age_ever: 0
              member_count: 4
              priority_group_activation: 0
              allow_snat: yes
              reselect_tries: 0
              enabled_status: enabled
              active_member_count: 0
              server_ip_tos: pass-through
              server_link_qos: pass-through
              queue_on_connection_limit: no
              queue_depth_limit: 0
              minimum_up_members_action: failover
              allow_nat: yes
              lb_method: round-robin
              all_avg_queue_entry_age: 0
              ignore_persisted_weight: no
              server_side_bits_out: 0
              all_num_connections_serviced: 0
              minimum_active_members: 0
              service_down_action: none
              server_side_current_connections: 0
              members:
                - real_session: monitor-enabled
                  rate_limit: no
                  inherit_profile: yes
                  real_state: down
                  address: 1.1.1.1
                  logging: no
                  monitors: []
                  ratio: 1
                  name: 1.1.1.1:3268
                  partition: Common
                  ephemeral: no
                  connection_limit: 0
                  state: offline
                  full_path: /Common/1.1.1.1:3268
                  fqdn_autopopulate: no
                  priority_group: 0
                  dynamic_ratio: 1
                - real_session: monitor-enabled
                  rate_limit: no
                  inherit_profile: yes
                  real_state: down
                  address: 2.2.2.2
                  logging: no
                  monitors: []
                  ratio: 1
                  name: 2.2.2.2:3268
                  partition: Common
                  ephemeral: no
                  connection_limit: 0
                  state: offline
                  full_path: /Common/2.2.2.2:3268
                  fqdn_autopopulate: no
                  priority_group: 0
                  dynamic_ratio: 1
                - real_session: monitor-enabled
                  rate_limit: no
                  inherit_profile: yes
                  real_state: down
                  address: 3.3.3.3
                  logging: no
                  monitors: []
                  ratio: 1
                  name: 3.3.3.3:3268
                  partition: Common
                  ephemeral: no
                  connection_limit: 0
                  state: offline
                  full_path: /Common/3.3.3.3:3268
                  fqdn_autopopulate: no
                  priority_group: 0
                  dynamic_ratio: 1
                - real_session: monitor-enabled
                  rate_limit: no
                  inherit_profile: yes
                  real_state: down
                  address: 3.3.3.3
                  logging: no
                  monitors: []
                  ratio: 1
                  name: 3.3.3.3:3268
                  partition: Common
                  ephemeral: no
                  connection_limit: 0
                  state: offline
                  full_path: /Common/3.3.3.3:3268
                  fqdn_autopopulate: no
                  priority_group: 0
                  dynamic_ratio: 1
              all_max_queue_entry_age_ever: 0
              queue_time_limit: 0
              status_reason: The children pool member(s) are down
              server_side_pkts_out: 0
              server_side_total_connections: 0
              pool_num_connections_serviced: 0
              client_link_qos: pass-through
              name: test
              pool_num_connections_queued_now: 0
              minimum_up_members: 0
              all_queue_head_entry_age: 0
              slow_ramp_time: 10
              server_side_pkts_in: 0
              client_ip_tos: pass-through
              minimum_up_members_checking: no
              all_num_connections_queued_now: 0
              availability_status: offline
              pool_avg_queue_entry_age: 0
              total_requests: 0
              full_path: /Common/test
        poolName: test
```

This yields the recap:

```
PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************

TASK [Display Config for a specific Virtual Server using a variable] **********************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=test) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "Members": [
            {
                "name": "1.1.1.1:3268"
            },
            {
                "name": "2.2.2.2:3268"
            },
            {
                "name": "3.3.3.3:3268"
            },
            {
                "name": "3.3.3.3:3268"
            }
        ],
        "Method": "round-robin",
        "Monitors": [
            "/Common/tcp"
        ],
        "name": "test"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: That worked. What is weird I thought I had done that. I must have had a brace or bracket pr quote in the wrong place as when I did it it returned "null" for memebers. Thanks much.